# REST API Implementation Sample Code

Tags: php, json, rest

I know nothing about implementing an API. I do know PHP a bit. I have a situation where I need to call a REST API method to purge cache on a CDN server. Can somebody help me with some sample code?

The following is the sample request:

```
PUT <<url>>
Authorization: TOK:12345-12345
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Host: api.edgecast.com
Content-Length: 87
{
   "MediaPath":"<<urlhere>>"
   "MediaType":"3"
}
```

Can somebody help me with code to implement this rest api request?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I had to find the hard way too. This has been tested (with slight modifications from my original code)

```
//## GoGrid PHP REST API Call

define('TOKEN','XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXX');     // found on the cdn admin My Settings
define('ACCOUNT_NUMBER','XXXX');        // found on the cdn admin Top Right corner

function purgeCacheFileFromCDN($urlToPurge) {
  //## Build the request
  $request_params = (object) array('MediaPath' =>  $urlToPurge, 'MediaType' => 8);   // MediaType 8=small 3=large
  $data = json_encode($request_params);

  //## setup the connection and call.
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.edgecast.com/v2/mcc/customers/'.ACCOUNT_NUMBER.'/edge/purge');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);                  // For debugging
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);             // no caching  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);            // no caching  
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: tok:'.TOKEN, 'Content-Type: application/json','Accept: application/json', 'Content-length: '.strlen($data)));
  $head = curl_exec($ch);
  $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

  //## check if error
  if ($httpCode['http_code'] != 200) {
    echo 'Error reported: '.print_r(array($head,$httpCode),1);  // output it to stdout this will be emailed to me via cron capture.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was too lazy to write from the scratch so copied from *[amazingly pink](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2009/PUTting-data-fields-with-PHP-cURL)* site that Google advises in the first page of results.

```
    $data = array("a" => $a);
    $ch = curl_init($this->_serviceUrl . $id);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if(!$response) {
        return false;
    }
```

PS: The source search request: http://www.google.ru/search?q=php+sample+put+request+curl

Comment: My God, it is amazingly pink. And there's a weird fairy lady. +1

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/gnitnuj/aba5e09f1fa6a98be803#file-readme-md) is my source gist for my fully implemented Grunt task for anyone else thinking about working with the EdgeCast API. You'll find in my example that I use a node module to execute the curl command which purges the CDN.

This was that I ended up with after spending hours trying to get an HTTP request to work within Node. I was able to get one working in Ruby and Python, but did not meet the requirements of this project.